# Yii CGridView bulk edit/update?

Tags: php, yii

I want to edit/update, multiple rows together in Yii CGridView.
Say, each row has a checkbox and a single edit/update button, I select multiple rows and by clicking on edit/update button all selected rows are opened for editing and update.

Is this possible with Yii CGridView..??

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selectableRows` property of the `CGridView`.

According to [Yii Documentation for CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#selectableRows-detail)

> public integer $selectableRows;
>
> the number of table body rows that can be selected. If 0, it means rows cannot be selected. If 1, only one row can be selected. If 2 or any other number, it means multiple rows can be selected. A selected row will have a CSS class named 'selected'.

You can use the the `$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(containerID)` to retrieve the key values of the selected rows.

Add some more buttons either at the top or bottom of the gridview with actions for edit, delete or whatever action you need to take and pass the key values retrieved above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit rows in-line you can use extension phaActiveColumn which I messed up to support multiple rows (the whole table if desired).

EDIT: well, the extension basically creates an input field replacing the grid cell when user clicks on the cell. The field will have the cell's value for starters and it then sends an ajax call to controller, as soon as the user presses enter, asking to save the value of the field, which will be the user's input.

My addition was to create one such field for every cell in the row and store user input in javascript objects which then get send all at once with one ajax call to the controller. Multiple row updates are supported (creating adequate number of javascript objetcs).

If anyone has any interest in this there it is.

[phaEditColumn2](http://www.simplebills.gr/attachments/public/phaEditColumn2.php.txt)

[phaAbsActiveColumn2](http://www.simplebills.gr/attachments/public/phaAbsActiveColumn2.php.txt)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.